# Usefullness of Python Transformer Exception Pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, design-patterns, except

I was reading up on the various error-handling patterns and I came across the so-called "Transformer" pattern. It's exemplified as such:

```
try:
    something()
except SomeError as err:
    logger.warn("...")
    raise DifferentError() from err
```

Why would you want to do this? Why not just use DifferentError from the start? An example of this being needed may help.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t always have control over what error `something` will raise. Take for example this little function

```
def determinant_2by2(matrix: [list]):
    return matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]
```

It takes a 2x2 matrix and returns it’s determinant. But

```
print(
    determinant_2by2([[2,0],[0]])
)
```

will result in an `IndexError`. But that doesn’t tell you in detail how it failed. Instead we can do

```
def determinant_2by2(matrix: [list]):
    try:
        return matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]
    except IndexError:
        raise Exception('Shape of matrix not 2x2')
    

print(
    determinant_2by2([[2,0],[0]])
)
```

which clearly communicates what’s wrong

Answer (score 2):

A common scenario is when you want to raise a more specific error. For example,

```py
class FrobozzParseError(Exception):
    pass

class Frobozz:
    def __init__(self, value):
        try:
            self.parsed = self._parse(value)
        except IndexError as err:
            raise FrobozzParseError(err)
```

Now, the caller can handle IndexError and FrobozzParseError as different cases, and thus for example ignore the specific error (because you know exactly what could have caused it, and know how to recover) while allowing other IndexError cases to still cause a traceback.